# line chart bug in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

When I try to draw a line chart for 2 different measures against years ( years are x-axis and the results are y-axis) when some years do not have values corresponding for one of the two measures it gives the value of the available measure to the other one.

I tried to draw two lines which is two different measures calculating the same calculation but over 2 different facilities (dimension table) and expected it to give blanks where the selected facility has no values